# How can I get razor views to compile when using NancyFX?

Tags: razor, teamcity, nancy

We have a large Nancy FX web project running under ASP.NET which has many razor views. I'd like for the views to be compiled by the build server (Teamcity using MSBuild). I don't care about pre-compilation - I'm only concerned with catching compilation errors in the views.

I've tried true but it has no affect.

Answer (score 1):

You can't precompile views, but you should be able to catch all the compilation errors using [tests](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Testing-your-application).